# get value from checkbox but not the word from checkbox

Tags: html, checkbox

I have two checkbox and under this when tick one of two checkbox I have two another option checkbox and another tick there will be text. The text will be value from the checkbox, how can I get the value from this checkbox? But the text I want to put are different sentence for each option checkbox selected not the word from checkbox. Did anyone know?

And my another problem is the checkbox not working if I do not tick the first checkbox.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ShowHideDiv(Cat) {
    var dvCat = document.getElementById("bigCat");
    bigCat.style.display = Cat.checked ? "block" : "none";
  }
</script>

<label for="Cat">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Cat" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" /> Cat 
</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function ShowHideDiv2(Rabbit) {
    var bigRabbit = document.getElementById("bigRabbit");
    bigRabbit.style.display = Rabbit.checked ? "block" : "none";
  }
</script>

<label for="Rabbit">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Rabbit" onclick="ShowHideDiv2(this)" /> Rabbit 
</label>

<div id="bigCat" style="display: none">

  <label> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="bigSubCat" /> British shorthair 
</label>

  <label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="bigSubCat" /> Exotic Shorthair 
</label>

  <div id="bigRabbit" style="display: none">

    <label> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="bigSubRabbit" /> White Rabbit
</label>

    <label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="bigSubRabbit" /> Black Rabbit 
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add value attribute to the checkbox. and set value to the checkbox.Or you can take the text from the label

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ShowHideDiv(Cat) {
    var dvCat = document.getElementById("bigCat");
    bigCat.style.display = Cat.checked ? "block" : "none";
    console.log(Cat.value)
    console.log("Text Inside LABEL:" + Cat.parentNode.textContent )

  }
</script>

<label for="Cat">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Cat" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" value="cat"/> Cat 
</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function ShowHideDiv2(Rabbit) {
    var bigRabbit = document.getElementById("bigRabbit");
    bigRabbit.style.display = Rabbit.checked ? "block" : "none";
console.log(Rabbit.value) 
 console.log("Text Inside LABEL:" + Rabbit.parentNode.textContent )
  }
</script>

<label for="Rabbit">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Rabbit" onclick="ShowHideDiv2(this)" value="Rabbit"/> Rabbit 
</label>

<div id="bigCat" style="display: none">

  <label> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="bigSubCat" /> British shorthair 
</label>

  <label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="bigSubCat" /> Exotic Shorthair 
</label>
</div>
  <div id="bigRabbit" style="display: none">

    <label> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="bigSubRabbit" /> White Rabbit
</label>

    <label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="bigSubRabbit" /> Black Rabbit 
</label>
```

Comment: thank u so much my another problem about "the checkbox not working if I do not tick the first checkbox" solve now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow this simple logic:

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/6p7zkfwf/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" value="This is option one!" id="opt1"><label for="opt1">Option One</label>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" value="This is option two!" id="opt2"><label for="opt2">Option Two</label>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.container input[type=checkbox]');

for (let i = 0, l = checkboxes.length; i < l; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(checkboxes[i].parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML == "") {
        checkboxes[i].parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML = checkboxes[i].value;
    } else {
        checkboxes[i].parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML = "";
    }

  });
}
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```